# Using INDIRECT in a column validation with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am trying to set a column's data validation using the INDIRECT function. In Excel is looks like this:[Excel Data Validation using INDIRECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAnoB.png)

I am using one cells contents to refernce a named table as the source of the data validation.

The code in ClosedXML that I was hoping would accomplish this is:

```
worksheet.Column(columnNumber).SetDataValidation().List("=INDIRECT(R[0]C[-1])");
```

I just want to reference the cell in the column to the left of the currenct cell to pull the table to use for data validation.  This produces an error, and removes all data validation from the workbook. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing ClosedXML doesn't support the `INDIRECT` function.